# Switch Fragment with default Android Studio navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm a little bit lost with the implementation of the navigation drawer in Android Studio. The onCreate method call the `PlaceholderFragment` class which I don't really understand what is it for.

But anyway, where should I implement my `onItemClickListener` to display different `fragments` according to the item selected in the navigation drawer ?

This is my current PlaceholderFragment :

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private CustomAdapter expenseAdapter;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        expenseAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity());

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvExpense);
        listView.setAdapter(expenseAdapter);
        expenseAdapter.loadObjects();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String expense = expenseAdapter.getItem(position).get("title").toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), expense, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

PS : the `onItemClickListener` in the class is for another `ListView` which is not the one in the navigation drawer. Basically I'm using parse.com and populating a `ListView` with items from the db.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm finally using this code within `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SearchFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    }
```

In `fragment = new HomeFragment();`, android studio tell me that the android.support.v4.app.fragment is needed. Why is that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(In case you didn't do this) : In AndroidStudio, it is better to generate sample Activity with Navigation Drawer (Alt+Insert -> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity (on Android Studio 0.8.+))
You will get activity that hosts NavigationDrawerFragment with some drawables.

In NavigationDrawerFragment `onCreateView` you populate list items you want to be displayed in the drawer, and activity will automatically implement interface `NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks` with method `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)`. This method is called when you click on item at certain position in Navigation Drawer, and in this method you replace `R.id.container` with the fragment you need on that position.

You don't have to use `PlaceholderFragment`, it is the mock to be displayed at first time, before you implement your own. Feel free to delete it and create any fragment you want.

And `OnItemClickListener` is already implemented in method `onCreateView` of NavigationDrawerFragment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So in the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method, I should just use a switch case ?   And replace in : fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit(); the PlaceholderFragment with anything I want ?

Comment: When creating my Fragment , what should I use considering I'm using the drawer from Android Studio ? android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment ?

Comment: better use android.app.Fragment, though another variant is also possible (with some changes)

Comment: I have some problem not using de support.v4. See the edit in my question.

Comment: use getFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: And the very last question: If I want a default DrawerItem to be displayed, how should I do since I dont have access to savedInstanceState ? Thank you very much for everything

Comment: do you mean you want to display certain Fragment as default when the app is opened ? If yes, there is call selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition); in onCreate of NavigationDrawerFragment, it determines which DrawerItem is active by default, replace it with, for example selectItem(1) if you want secondFragment be active on app opening

Comment: Thx a lot for everything. That's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder fragment is just that.  It is a blank fragment that is used in the auto-generated code to show you how to use the navigation drawer.  You can use any fragment with the navigation drawer.

You can display a fragment when an item is selected in the onNavigationDrawerItemSeleced(int position) that is in the activity that implements NavigationDrawerFragment.  You can use a FragmentManager to swap out the old fragment with the new.